# need a map that preserves order and has "order sensitive" equals/hashCode

Tags: java, collections

Is there a java collection that works like a LinkedHashMap but reflects the order also in equals and hashCode? 
-> two Maps with same elements but different order should not be equal and should have different hashCodes.

**Solution based on Peter Lawrey's answer (xAxis is the LinkedHashMap):**

hashCode:

```
...
result = prime * result + ((xAxis == null) ? 0 : xAxis.hashCode() + xAxis.toString().hashCode());
...
```

equals:

```
...
if (xAxis == null) {
        if (other.xAxis != null) {
            return false;
        }
    } else if (!xAxis.equals(other.xAxis)) {
        return false;
    } else if (!xAxis.toString().equals(other.xAxis.toString())) {
        return false;
    }
...
```

(it based on code generated by eclipse)

Comment: Nope. Only if you create a field in the class for 'order'

Comment: Have you try guava.Maps.difference(left, right)?

Comment: it seems guava.Maps.difference(left, right) is not order sensitive?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the hashCode and equals of HashMap.

Since HashMap has no order, this is very dangerous but you can do it if you want.  You might find that comparing the toString() of each is all you really need.

BTW: To get an idea of how many different orders you can have for a keys of a HashMap, this blog post gives you an idea using HashSet (which uses the same code)

http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2011/09/order-of-elements-in-hash-collection.html

Comment: Why not overriding equals and hashCode for LinkedHashMap?

Comment: You could override equals and hashCode for LinkedHashMap if the order was important to you. Again, you might find that comparing `toString()` is all you need.

Comment: the only problem i have with overriding equals/hashCode is that it conflicts with AbstractMap. Probably it is enough to override equal in the object that uses the map->great idea - with toString!

Comment: @dermoritz I use `toString` is unit tests for collections all the time. It a quick way to check all the elements are as expected. I also tend to use LinkedHashMap rather than HashMap just so the order of elements is more predictable. (which also makes debugging easier)

Answer (score 1):

The contract of `Map` is quite clear about what equality means. (The fact that even Java library `Map`s break the contract is par for the Java collections course.) Breaking LSP also causes confusion if you consider, say, comparing a contract-complying `Map` with a contract-breaker.

A clean solution is to a layer of indirection. Introduce a class that contains but does not implement `Map` (can be any implementation, could even change implementation at runtime, although probably shouldn't) and does it's own `equals`/`hashCode` thing.

Comment: upvote for pointing on "map contract". this was also my concern on simply overrriding hashCode/equals. I overrode equals/hashCode in the class that uses the maps.

Answer (score 0):

How about http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html

Comment: Can you use a Java 7 javadoc?

Comment: Do you realize that Java 5's EOL was 3 years ago?

Comment: tree map is the worst of all - it changes the order that i want to save.

Comment: It does **NOT** if you make an order - specify your own comparator methods to maintain your order.
@StephenC - sorry, this was the first link that came up in Google, I did not even notice Java version until now - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html is up-to-date

Comment: the problem is that the order to be preserved is random - the user sets the order!

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap a `LinkedHashMap` with a `Map` implementation and provide an `equals`/`hashCode` that computes equality based on order.